# Webcomponent / custom-element instance stops parsing on first <script> tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-component, custom-element

Using Google Chrome (v42) and the native webcomponents support, I am trying to use a custom element, where the custom element content sometimes contains inlined javascript tags. However, the parser seems to stop parsing the element content whenever it encounters the first `<script>` tag. What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure my custom element knows it's entire content when the initializer (e.g. createdCallback) runs?

Simplified example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      document.registerElement("element-count", {
        prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
          createdCallback: {
            value: function(){
              this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.children.length));
            }
          }
        })
      })
    </script>

    <element-count>
      <div>alpha</div>
      <script></script><!-- this is here just to show that the parser stops -->
      <div>beta</div>
    </element-count>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected result:

```
alpha
beta
3
```

Actual result:

```
alpha
2
beta
```

The custom element's createdCallback runs as soon as the parser encounters the `<script>` element.

I don't have much control over the document fragment within the custom element (inside of the `<element-count>`). The real-world version of the custom component tries to wrap arbitrary DOM fragments into richly decorated boxes and do  some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You're right it's because the custom element is not parsed yet when `createdCallback` is called.

Use the `body.onload` event.
Or put the script that call `registerElement` **after** the custom element.

```
<html>
<body onload="register()">
    <script>
    function register()
    {
        document.registerElement( "element-count", {
            prototype: Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype, {
                createdCallback: {
                    value: function ()
                    {
                        this.appendChild( document.createTextNode( this.children.length ) );
                    }
                }
            } )
        } )
    }
   </script>
   <element-count id="c">
        <script></script><!-- this is here just to show that the parser stops --> 
        <div>alpha</div>
        <div>beta</div>
    </element-count>

<button onclick="alert(c.children.length)">Recount</button>
```